# Creating an ArrayList from textfield

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

I am just creating a random java gui application which takes customer details and want to store it in an arraylist. I have done just this simple code of my knowledge but it isnt working. can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance. This is my code below:

```
  ArrayList<Database> PropertyList= new ArrayList<Database>();
    Database database= new Database(PropertyType,Address,Area,NoOfBedroom,NoOfToilets,Garage,OwnerName,OwnerAddress,OwnerPhoneNo,OwnerEmail);
    PropertyList.add(database);
    for (int i = 0 ; i<5 ;i++){
       System.out.println(PropertyList.get(i).getAddress()); 
    }
```

Comment: You haven't added 5 `Database` type instances in your `PropertyList`. Also you should be having `getAddress()` in your `Database` class.

Comment: what are you trying to do,
basically your arrayList has one object only and if you iterate this arrayList 
you will get **IndexOutOfBoundException**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users point out, you have only one object in your ArrayList and IndexOutOfBoundException will happen when i >= 1 in this function call PropertyList.get(i).

If you are not sure how many elements are there inside the ArrayList, you should make use of the ArrayList .size() method inside the for loop condition.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < PropertyList.size(); i++){
   System.out.println(PropertyList.get(i).getAddress()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks jie Heng for ur help . It works for me thanks again